# MySQL InnoDB doubled IDs

Tags: mysql, innodb, foreign-key-relationship, relationship

http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/8241/stackoverflow.png

I created a new databese. There are 2 tables `class` and `teacher`. There is a field `class_leader` in the table `class` related with `teacher_id` from `teacher`. [1]

In PHPMyAdmin relationship looks like: [2]

Table `teacher` contains some records. [3]

When I add new records at table `class`: [4]

Why IDs in `class_leader` are doubled? [5]

What does it means? What should i do?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "IDs in class_leader are doubled. Perhaps you could show us some data, and explain what you expect to happen. Looking at the page, I suspect you may want a one-to-many relationship, as one teacher may presumably have more than one class.

Comment: At screenshot (part 5) you may see  "2-", "-2", "1-" and "-1" values. I want to understand why it happening.

Comment: Yes, it does look rather strange. What do you get when you try `SELECT class_leader FROM class` in an SQL session?

Comment: It SQL query return just "1" and "2". http://img827.imageshack.us/img827/9721/image028.png

Comment: I have a idea that it is just PHPMyAdmin error. The databse is correct. What you think about that?

Comment: I suspected that might be the case; numbers like `1-` look a bit spurious to me. I don't know what to do about it, though. I've never been able to get phpMyAdmin even to start on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the relationship between class and teacher is many-to-one. It's normal to have duplicate ids in the class_leader column.

Sorry, I did not see the screenshot. If you don't have the class_leader field as unique, it's normal to have duplicate ids. Make it a column with unique values and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But i'm set relationship one-to-one, you may see it at first part of screenshot.

Comment: I set `class_leader` as UNIQUE value, but nothing changes.

Comment: It would help if you had some piece of code to see how you do the insertion.

Comment: INSERT INTO `school`.`class` (
`class_id` ,
`class_number` ,
`class_letter` ,
`class_quantity` ,
`class_shedule` ,
`class_leader` 
)
VALUES (
NULL , '5', 'C', '25', '17', '1'
); -------- In PHPMyAdmin it looks like http://img684.imageshack.us/img684/9715/image024.png

Comment: If you set the class_leader column to be unique, it would fail with an error, since there are duplicate values. Can you please issue a __show create table__ command for both tables and attach the output here?

Comment: In the class table, you have two indexes on the class_leader column. Delete the non-unique one.

Comment: I did it. But nothing changes. May be leave everything as is? It seems that everything works.

Comment: I have a idea that it is just PHPMyAdmin error. The databse is correct. What you think about that?